# Smart way to put div center instead of real number?

Tags: html, css

The son div can be put in the center with real number in margin.

```css
div.father {
height: 330px;
width: 330px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

div.son {
margin:114px 114px 114px 114px;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

The son div can be put in the center.
[image]

Maybe there is another smart way instead of `margin:114px 114px 114px 114px;`,if the border width was changed ,then the margin number will be changed accordingly,how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flexbox` module seems a smart and modern candidate for this task

`justify-content` aligns the item along the *main axis* (horizontally) and `align-items` aligns the item along the *cross-axis* (vertically)

```
div.father {
    height: 330px;
    width: 330px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.son {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdJVvW) and [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (IE10+)

Answer (score 7):

one way by which you can achieve this is by settting parent `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` and for son `margin:auto`

```css
div.father {
height: 330px;
width: 330px;
border: 1px solid black;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}

div.son {
margin:auto;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If .son div's width and height will remain same, then below code will work for you.

```css
div.father {
height: 330px;
width: 330px;
border: 1px solid black;
position:relative;
}

div.son {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
<div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve a centering, depending on what the exact requirements are.

One example could be positioning the child absolutely (and the parent relatively), setting margin to auto and the distance from each side to 0.

```css
div.father {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 330px;
  position: relative;
  width: 330px;
}
div.son {
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

For a full guide of centering stuff in CSS I recommend [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) page. It has full guide for every kind of centering.